# Comparing Comma Separate Value with Comma Separated Values SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table A which contain column "ColumnName" (it will contain the comma separated integer values ) and I have store procedure which take parameter which is also comma separated integer values.
For example I have values in table "101,102,103" and "103,104,105" and User input is "101,104" it should return 2 record. how can I achieve this?
Need SQL statements

Comment: Fix your data model so you are not storing numbers as string values, in delimited strings!

Comment: What Gordon said -- and if you *must*, see [this](http://sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html).

Comment: If they're comma delimited values, then they can't be an `int` datatype. `int` can't store multiple values. You're clearly using a `varchar`, which is the wrong datatype for storing numerical data, unless of course, you want behaviour like`'10' < '2' = TRUE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetMatches(@input varchar (100))
AS
BEGIN

    WITH CTE AS
    (
        SELECT value AS number
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(@input, ',') 
    )
    SELECT CTE.number, A.ColumnName
    FROM A
    INNER JOIN CTE
    ON ',' + A.ColumnName + ',' LIKE '%,' + CTE.number + ',%';

END
```

You can test the stored procedure like this:

```
EXEC dbo.GetMatches @input = '101,104';
```

Comment: Is there any performance issue regarding this like operator usage?

Comment: @AsimSajjad The real performance issue comes from the data model. It would be better to store the integer values in a column with an integer datatype. Given that the integer values are stored in a comma separated varchar column then the LIKE operator is a much used built-in operator that is optimized to do its job very fast.

Comment: Morten: What would you suggest , is it better to used it like I have mean comma separated value or better to have separate table which will have integer value to search instead of comma separate value ?

Comment: @AsimSajjad My opinion regarding performance optimization is to only do changes to speed things up if in fact you are experiencing problems with performance. If things work fast enough with your current table layout and my stored procedure then stick to it. If your table holds less than 1 million rows then you are not likely to have any performance problems after all.

Comment: Morten: The suggestion which we have to change is to don't store comma separated integer values in one table column, instead we have created lookup table to store the comma separated value against each record and then make join with that table ,

Comment: Yes, that is the normal way to do it. I'm glad if I was of any help to you!

Answer (score 0):

If you need help, explanations, let me know :)

```
DECLARE 
    @input  VARCHAR(MAX) = '101,104', 
    @separator CHAR(1) =',',
    @separatorPosition INT,
    @value VARCHAR(MAX),
    @start INT = 1

DECLARE @split_input TABLE(Value VARCHAR(MAX))
DECLARE @tmp TABLE (st VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @tmp VALUES ('101,102,103')
INSERT INTO @tmp VALUES ('103,104,105')
INSERT INTO @tmp VALUES ('106,107,108')

SET @separatorPosition = CHARINDEX(@separator, @input)


 IF @separatorPosition = 0
 BEGIN
     INSERT INTO @split_input
     VALUES
     (
         @input
     )
     RETURN
 END

 SET @input = @input + @separator

 WHILE @separatorPosition > 0
 BEGIN
     SET @value = SUBSTRING(@input, @start, @separatorPosition - @start)

     IF (@value <> '')
         INSERT INTO @split_input
         VALUES
         (
             @value
         )

     SET @start = @separatorPosition + 1
     SET @separatorPosition = CHARINDEX(@separator, @input, @start)
 END


 SELECT tmp.st FROM @tmp AS tmp INNER JOIN @split_input AS split ON tmp.st LIKE '%' + split.Value + '%'
```

Comment: The issue with this query will be if we input 6 then it will be matched with 106 am I right?

Answer (score 0):

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 GO
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
 GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnParseArray] (@Array VARCHAR(MAX),@separator CHAR(1))

RETURNS @T Table (col1 varchar(50))

AS 

BEGIN

-- @Array is the array we wish to parse

 -- @Separator is the separator charactor such as a comma

  DECLARE @separator_position INT -- This is used to locate each separator character

  DECLARE @array_value VARCHAR(MAX) -- this holds each array value as it is returned

 -- For my loop to work I need an extra separator at the end. I always look to the

  -- left of the separator character for each array value



  SET @array = @array + @separator



 -- Loop through the string searching for separtor characters

  WHILE PATINDEX('%' + @separator + '%', @array) <> 0 

  BEGIN

-- patindex matches the a pattern against a string

SELECT @separator_position = PATINDEX('%' + @separator + '%',@array)

SELECT @array_value = LEFT(@array, @separator_position - 1)

-- This is where you process the values passed.

INSERT into @T VALUES (@array_value)    

-- Replace this select statement with your processing

-- @array_value holds the value of this element of the array

-- This replaces what we just processed with and empty string

SELECT @array = STUFF(@array, 1, @separator_position, '')

END

RETURN 

 END


select * from [dbo].[fnParseArray]('a,b,c,d',',')
```